# Using double-reflected objects

Tags: java, reflection, java-compiler-api

What I'm basically trying to do is invoke a method on an object whose class is written in a String and compiled through `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`
That part is "easy", I've used something similar to this: https://sites.google.com/site/malenkov/java/081217

However, the object I want to invoke a method on is a field in a different class also written in a String and compiled through JavaCompiler. What I have is:

```
MemoryClassLoader mcl1 = new MemoryClassLoader("Class1", Class1Content);
MemoryClassLoader mcl2 = new MemoryClassLoader("Class2", Class2Content);
Class c1 = mcl1.loadClass("Class1");
Class c2 = mcl2.loadClass("Class2");
Field f = c1.getDeclaredField("current"); //current should be of type Class2
Object obj = f.get(c2.newInstance()); //trying to cast the Field to type Class2 so I can invoke Class2 methods on it
Method m = c2.getDeclaredMethod("Class2Method");
System.out.println(m.invoke(obj));
```

Important code in Class1 (aka in String variable Class1Content):

```
Class1Content = "public MemoryClassLoader mcl = new MemoryClassLoader(\"" + "Class2" + "\", Class2Content);\n" +
                "Class c = mcl.loadClass(\"" + "Class2" + "\");\n" +
                "public Object current;\n" + //the object I will try to invoke a method on
                "public Class1()throws Exception{\n" +
                "Field f = c.getDeclaredField(\"initialState\");" + // initialState is the name of the field in Class2 I'm trying to have in Class1
                "current = f.get(c.newInstance()); c.cast(current);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

When I try to run the first block of code I get an exception at line `Object state = f.get(c2.newInstance());`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not
>   set java.lang.Object field Class1.current to Class2

Is there any way I can do what I'm trying to achieve or do I have to go back to the drawing board?
Thanks!

Comment: `MemoryClassLoader` is the one from the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryClassLoader` extends `ClassLoader`, so your two classes are loaded with different ClassLoaders.  Unless you have specified some relationship between the ClassLoaders, classes loaded by one will not be seen by the other.  I would try modifying the `MemoryClassLoader` so that one instance can load both classes.